# Using Python with WAMP

Tags: python, apache, wamp

I use [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) for my PHP and MySQL development. I want to start learning Python for use in web development. Is there a way for me to use Python within WAMP?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: yes, use [MOD_WSGI](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) (not [MOD_PYTHON](http://www.modpython.org/)).

Long answer: yes, what do you want to use it for? Server-side scripting? Code generation?

Comment: Your short answer can be even shorter as mod_python is now officially a dead project and really shouldn't be recommended to new users. See 'http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2010/06/modpython-project-is-now-officially.html'.

Comment: Server-side scripting? Code generation?

Is there a difference between both when setting up the environment?

Comment: this was very useful for me while setting up: http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide